# Zend Form Decorators to embed label and elements

Tags: css, zend-framework, decorator

I have absolutely no idea how to use the decorators in Zend!

If you create a basic straightforward form without decorators, the labels go in DT and the elements go into DD. And they all go one after another.

So how do I make it so that each label and its corresponding element also go inside a div?

Thanks so much!
Kousha

Answer (score 0):

I love decorators!  But they are extremely hard to master.  Its a good thing your questions is an easy one.

I use a function this in my forms

```
public function getElementDecorators()
{
    return array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Errors',
        array('Description', array('tag' => 'p', 'class' => 'description')),
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd', 'id'  => array('callback' => array(get_class($this), 'resolveElementId')))),
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt')),
        array(array('elementContainer' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'element-container')),
    );
}
```

then for each of my elements in the form I create them like so.

```
$this->addElement('Text', 'wordup', array(
    'label' => 'Put your words here',
    'attribs' => array('class' => 'textbox-fancy'),
    'decorators' => $this->getElementDecorators()
));
```